# addEventListener for only first focus of tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

What is event for (only)first opening of a tab from addon?
The tab `newTab` is opened earlier.
My code is:

```
var newTabBrowser = tabbrowser.getBrowserForTab(newTab);
newTabBrowser.addEventListener("focus", function () { 
    newTabBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML +="<div>hello world</div>";
    newTabBrowser.contentDocument.title = "hello world";
}, true);
```

Focus will add hello world every time its unfocused and focused again.
Load will fire it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the `pageshow` event and use a boolean flag to run your code once.